# Devexpres PivotGrid Export to Excel PivotGridOptionsPrint

Tags: c#, devexpress

I am using **DevExpress** in my projects,
I have a **Pivotgrid** and I want to export to Excel, but merged cells are not created in Excel as merged.
I want to use `PivotGridOptionsPrint` but I cant create this class with eventhandler `optionsChanged`.

```
PivotGridOptionsPrint op = new PivotGridOptionsPrint(??)
```

what parameters do I need?

Devexpress version 15.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through the documentation for the [PivotGridOptionsPrint.MergeRowFieldValues](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraPivotGridPivotGridOptionsPrint_MergeRowFieldValuestopic) Property and [PivotGridOptionsPrint.MergeColumnFieldValues](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraPivotGridPivotGridOptionsPrint_MergeColumnFieldValuestopic) Property.

> **Note:** The MergeRowFieldValues property is used to customize Pivot Grid export settings when data is exported in the WYSIWYG export mode.
>   This property is not in effect for the data-aware mode. To customize
>   the Pivot Grid export settings while exporting in data-aware mode, use
>   the DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.PivotXlsExportOptions and
>   DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.PivotXlsxExportOptions descendants.

Along this you can get more information about at [Exporting](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1800) documentation of the XtraPivotGrid